# How to save typed function arguments and pass to function in Python?

Tags: python, typing

Let's say I define the following function with typed arguments:

```py
from typing import List

def map_names_to_ages(names: List[str], ages: List[int]):
    return { name: ages[index] for index, name in enumerate(names) }
```

And I have another function with the same arguments:

```py
def generate_sentence(names: List[str], ages: List[int]):
    return [f"{name} is {ages[index]} years old" for index, name in enumerate(names)]
```

What if I want to define the typed input arguments only once? Can I save and reuse them somehow? Something like this:

```py
args = ...
def map_names_to_ages(args):
    ...
def generate_sentence(args):
    ...
```

Comment: Function signatures can't be obfuscated like that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
StringList = List[str]
def map_names_to_ages(args: StringList):
    ...
def generate_sentence(args: StringList):
    ...
```

The types are nothing magical, they are just values like anything else. The only reason `StringList` starts with a capital here is convention.

EDIT: I might have misunderstood the question, if you want to define the signature of the function only once.

It is semi-possible with decorators:

```
from typing import Callable, List


def string_list(f: Callable[[List[str], List[int]], None]) -> Callable[[List[str], List[int]], None]:
    def wrapper(names: List[str], ages: List[int]) -> None:
        f(names, ages)
    return wrapper


@string_list
def map_names_to_ages(*args):
    pass


@string_list
def generate_sentence(names, ages):
    pass

@string_list
def generate_sentence(porcupines, stevedores):
    pass
```

but not a good idea in general because it does obfuscate the signature.

Comment: OP asked about combination of typed arguments: `(names: List[str], ages: List[int])`, not just one type of a single argument

Comment: Interesting idea with decorators, but `string_list` returns function unchanged, so it will still have 1 argument `args` and does not comply with decorators type hints.

Comment: Yup, that is duck-typing for you. I did say "semi-possible". The type checker _should_ pick up that the signature doesn't match though; although it will probably say that the problem is with the decorator rather than the function. In short, not a good idea.

Comment: A better thought out decorator could fix the signature problem too, it still wouldn't be a good pattern.

Comment: The problem is that you can't use your functions the same way because now they only have one argument, instead of two as originally intended. So this isn't even semi-possible

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych There. Now the signature of the returned function is correct, and the program will crash because the functions don't match the signature. Obviously you still need to write correct code but that's a given.